# c# Get the filename out of a linux format path

Tags: c#

I know, for a Windows file, we are able to use "Path.GetFileName(filepath)" to get the file name.  Is there a function will return the file name if the filepath is Linux format.

Like:  /usr/ubuntu/myfolder/newfile.jpg  => "newfile.jpg"

Comment: You also have `var uri = new Uri(new Uri("file://"), filePath);`. `string fileName = uri.Segments.Last();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same function to get File name from filePath

```
string linuxFilePath = "/usr/ubuntu/myfolder/newfile.jpg";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(linuxFilePath));
```

Or you can use [`Split('/')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) with Linq [`.Last()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=netframework-4.8) function

```
 Console.WriteLine(linuxPath.Split('/').Last())
```

Output:

```
newfile.jpg
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AbJ7Y0)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use below code:

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("File://.../usr/ubuntu/myfolder/newfile.jpg");
```